# NSRegularExpression - how to match text that may have parentheses, brackets, etc

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I have text that may have parentheses, brackets, in it, and a substring that has the same text. How can I get these texts to match up via regular expression, but with case insensitivity?

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString* text = @"Hello (extreme elevation) - some longer string";
NSString* obj = @"hello (extreme elevation)";
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:obj
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:text
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
```

This doesn't match anything, and even if Obj has the hello capitalized, it won't match via regex, but will match via NSString rangeOfString. I want to be able to match obj to text in this case, and other cases where I may have brackets, like:

```
NSString* text = @"Hello [extreme elevation]";
NSString* obj = @"hello [extreme elevation]";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSRegularExpression escaping parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960528/nsregularexpression-escaping-parentheses)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of regular expressions, parentheses, square brackets, asterisks, plus signs, and other similar characters are called *meta-characters*. In order to match them you need to either

- Escape them with a backslash, or
- Enclose them in a pair of square brackets.

Recall that the backslash is interpreted by Objective-C compiler as well, so if you put your expression in a string literal, you need to double backslashes, like this:

```
NSString* obj = @"hello \\(extreme elevation\\)";
```

Square bracket approach would work here, too:

```
NSString* obj = @"hello [(]extreme elevation[)]";
```

(it works with all meta-characters except square brackets, which need to be escaped by backslashes):

```
NSString* obj = @"hello \\[extreme elevation\\]";
```